# Не работает .append

Tags: jquery, javascript

Все, что внутри .append не отображается, вне зависимости от того, что там. Консоль не выдает ошибок.

```
var count = 0;
function add_new_field(){
   count++;
   $('<input type="text" />')
   .attr('id','file_'+count)
   .attr('name','file_'+count)
    .append(
         $('<span id="del_'+count+'"><a href="#" onclick="$(\'#file_'+count+'\').remove();">X</a></span>')
         )
     .appendTo('#file_field');                 
}
```

Comment: Вы пытаетесь запихнуть что-то внутрь тэга input? Может, имелось в виду appendAfter?

Comment: тег input закрывается $('<input type="text" />'). дело не в этом, я меняла их местами, не отображается именно то, что в .append, в независимости от того, что до этого идет

Comment: я это и имел ввиду. Нельзя что-то воткнуть в input. Поменяйте append на appendAfter

Comment: TypeError: $(...).attr(...).attr(...).appendAfter is not a function
 

$('<input type="text" />')

Comment: упс, функция `after` вместо `append` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var count = 0;
function add_new_field() {
    count++;
    var input = $('<input type="text" id="file_'+count+'" name="file_'+count+'" />');
    var span  = $('<span id="del_'+count+'"><a href="#" onclick="$(\'#file_'+count+'\').remove();">X</a></span>');
    $('#file_field').append(input);
    $('#file_field').append(span);             
}
```